# Javamail and TLS? (not STARTTLS)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, ssl

I need to send an email using Javamail and TLS (not STARTTLS, but a dedicated smtp port just for SSL/TLS!). I only managed to find examples for gmail, that however use STARTTLS. Can somebody please post an example for normal SSL/TLS? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official examples for JavaMail with Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#gmail) use SMTPS (i.e. SMTP over SSL/TLS on a dedicated port) and not STARTTLS. Essentially, the properties using JavaMail should be `mail.smtps.*` instead of `mail.smtp.*`.

If you want to force a specific version of SSL/TLS, for example TLSv1.0, you'll need to create your own `SSLSocketFactory`, possibly wrapping the default `SSLSocketFactory` (or anything else you would have customised), but you need to call `sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1" })` before returning the socket.

You'll need to pass that `SSLSocketFactory` either as an instance via the `mail.smtps.ssl.socketFactory` configuration property, or as a fully qualified class name via `mail.smtps.ssl.socketFactory.class` (in this case, you class must implement a static method called `getDefault`).

To prevent MITM attacks, you also need to make the client verify the server host name: you need to set `mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity` to `true`, since it seems to be `false` by default.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, your answer was very helpful for me!

Answer (score 0):

For the records, based on Brunos answer:

```
private static void sendMailSSL(String host, int port, String user, String pass, String to, String from, String subj, String message) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException
{
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity", true);       

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);       
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);


    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, from));
    msg.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, to);
    msg.setSubject(subj);
    msg.setText(message);


    Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
    try {
        t.connect(host, port, user, pass);  
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    } finally {
        t.close();
    }
}
```

Please note that I didn't test if checkserveridentity is actually really considered. At least it really uses SSL :-)